# Use leaflets over pdf files using angularjs

Tags: pdf, leaflet, tagging, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to do something like this 
[leafletoverimage](http://aashiskhanal.com/tagging/).
Currently I am using background image and angular-leaflets tool for the click and comment.

I am trying to find out a way where I can have pdf file actually rendering on browsers, and able to click on different section of pdf file, have popover and enter comment about that section.

This is similar to what https://app.fieldlens.com/ and www.plangrid.com is doing.

is there something available in angularjs or any other solution is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find anything for this? I am looking for the same requirement.